# simulate a keypress in c#?

Tags: c#, string, output, keypress

I searched the internet and in the fourum but cant find how to do it. what i want to do is to send a text in a discord chat every 5 minutes. and i want to send it from my account so i want to write a simple console app thet just output text and an enter to another programe.
I tried the sendInput class but dident get it to work.

```
  [DllImport("user64.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        while (true)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
            SendInput
            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                SendKeys.
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

How do i do that?

Comment: did you try?   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

Answer (score 0):

Did you try send message like this?

[List of WM messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup)

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
const int WM_CHAR = 0x105;
const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

[DllImport("user64.dll")] 
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user64.dll")]
public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

    foreach (Process proc in processes)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
        //int F5= 0x00000074;
        SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr) 116, (IntPtr) 0);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```